# Sql – dividing of two results from select count query

Tags: sql

I have a table  `tbl_casebase` :

```
kd_casebase kd_penyakit kd_gejala
---------------------------------
    1   P01     G01
    3   P01     G03
    4   P02     G03
    5   P02     G04
    6   P03     G04
    7   P03     G05
    8   P03     G06
    9   P03     G07
    10  P04     G07
    11  P04     G08
    12  P05     G08
    13  P05     G09
    14  P05     G10
    15  P06     G10
    16  P06     G11
    17  P06     G12
    18  P07     G12
    19  P07     G13
    20  P07     G14
    21  P07     G15
    22  P08     G15
    23  P08     G16
    24  P09     G17
    25  P09     G18
```

I execute first select count query :

```
SELECT 
    kd_penyakit, COUNT(kd_penyakit) AS count1
FROM
    tbl_casebase
WHERE 
    kd_gejala = 'G01' OR kd_gejala = 'G03'
GROUP BY 
    kd_penyakit
```

Then I execute second select count query :

```
SELECT 
    kd_penyakit, COUNT(kd_penyakit) AS count2
FROM 
    tbl_casebase
GROUP BY 
    kd_penyakit
```

Now what I want to do is dividing both of the results, so should be like this :

Result #1:

```
kd_penyakit count1
-------------------
    P01     2
    P02     1
```

Result #2:

```
kd_penyakit  count2      
-------------------
    P01     2
    P02     2
    P03     4
    P04     2
    P05     3
    P06     3
    P07     4
    P08     2
    P09     2
```

And the divide process is like this :

```
2/2=1

1/2=0,5

0/4=0

0/2=0

0/3=0
```

and others

So how to write the query?

I've seen similar post btw but it does not match what I want.

Comment: (1) I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are using.  (2) Sample data and desired results should be in a text, tabular format in the question.  (3) The queries should be included as text.

Comment: Pls slso include what you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional counting - conditional statement within the `count()` function. Count function counts any non-null value, so if the criteria are met, a non-null value is returned, otherwise null. This way there is no need for subqueries and joins:

```
SELECT kd_penyakit, COUNT(case when kd_gejala in ('G01','G03') then 1 else null end)/COUNT(kd_penyakit) AS count1
FROM tbl_casebase
GROUP BY kd_penyakit
```